# How to use alternate glibc with existing libstdc++?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, glibc, libstdc++

I need to use a self-compiled version of `glibc` (2.18), newer than the default one on the system (2.15). I can compile&link a C++ program, but when I try to run it, I get errors about `libstdc++.so.6`. (C programs seems to work just fine.) Do I need to recompile `gcc` against the newer `glibc` for this to work? Why? (Update: I figured this part out, but I have a few other questions at the bottom.)

Here is a sample C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "ok\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/717706), I compiled it with:

```
g++ -Wl,--rpath=/path/to/glibc-2.18/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/path/to/glibc-2.18/lib/ld-2.18.so a.cpp
```

It compiles with no errors, then `ldd` says:

```
$ ldd a.out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff421fe000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3b96e7f000)
    libc.so.6 => /path/to/glibc-2.18/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3b96ad1000)
    libm.so.6 => /path/to/glibc-2.18/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3b967cf000)
    /path/to/glibc-2.18/lib/ld-2.18.so => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3b9719d000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3b965b9000)
```

But when I try to run it:

```
$ ./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is confusing because it looks like `ldd` finds `libstdc++.so.6` just fine (the specific version is `libstdc++.so.6.0.16`).

Update: The problem seems to have been (not sure) that the new `2.18` dynamic linker is using its own library path which includes only subfolders of `/path/to/glibc-2.18/lib`. I got the program to run by adding this new path, followed by the standard paths (`/lib', '/usr/lib`, etc) to `/path/to/glibc-2.18/etc/ld.so.conf` and running `/path/to/glibc-2.18/sbin/ldconfig`. More questions:

1. Do I absolutely need the new `2.18` dynamic linker to run a program with `glibc-2.18`? Can't the standard linker do it? (This would avoid me having to set up and continuously update the paths of the `2.18` dynamic linker.)
2. If I compile with the `2.18` dynamic linker but without `--rpath`, the program doesn't work. Why?
3. Should I be using `-L/path/to/glibc-2.18/lib` in the compilation command (in addition to `--rpath` and `--dynamic-linker`)?

Comment: Seems likely...  Maybe `strace` might give some insight as to whether it's actually reading the file and getting some other error.

Comment: I tried `strace`, and it shows that the `2.18` dynamic linker is only looking for `libstdc++` in subfolders of `/path/to/glibc-2.18/lib`. I tried without `-Wl,--dynamic-linker` (so, using the standard one) and then I get `SEGV`.

Comment: Can you use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `LD_PRELOAD` to coax it into working?

Comment: I managed to make it work by adding `/path/to/gdb-2.18/lib` followed by the standard paths (`/lib`, `/usr/lib`, etc) to `/path/to/gdb-2.18/etc/ld.so.conf` and running `/path/to/gdb-2.18/sbin/ldconfig`. My understanding is that this would tell the `2.18` linker to look in the old paths as well. However, now I'm confused as to why I still need `--rpath` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I absolutely need the new 2.18 dynamic linker to run a program with glibc-2.18?

Yes (well, almost. See footnote).

> This would avoid me having to set up and continuously update the paths of the 2.18 dynamic linker.

A common technique is to create a `g++` shell wrapper, e.g. `g++glibc2.18`, and encapsulate adding the necessary link arguments there. Then a simple `make CXX=g++glibc2.18` would do the right thing.

> Can't the standard linker do it?

No. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) for explanation.

> If I compile with the 2.18 dynamic linker but without --rpath, the program doesn't work. Why?

See the same answer.

> Should I be using -L/path/to/glibc-2.18/lib in the compilation command (in addition to --rpath and --dynamic-linker)?

Yes, if you want to use symbols that are present in glibc-2.18 but not present in your system library. Otherwise, no.

Footnote:

As an alternative, you could build your program without the special flags, then use "explicit loader invocation" to actually run it: `/path/to/glibc-2.18/lib/ld-2.18.so /path/to/a.out`.

Beware: this doesn't always work: if the program likes to re-`exec` itself (and under other rare conditions). You may also have trouble debugging it when it is invoked that way.

Comment: I'm accepting this, even though I still don't understand number 2, the `--rpath` issue. If you have a moment, can you please clarify? (I don't see how the linked answer explains it.)

Comment: Once I (a) I bake in the new rtl (`ld-2.18.so`), and (b) configure the new rtl's lib path to include the original ones (not covered in the other answer), why do I still need to bake in a run path? The new rtl should know about `/path/to/glibc-2.18/lib` because that is where it comes from. Is this an issue about directory ordering within the new rtl's lib path?? Because I tried placing `/path/to/glibc-2.18/lib` as the first element in `/path/to/glibc-2.18/etc/ld.so.conf` but it still doesn't work (without `--rpath`).

Comment: @mmd If `/path/to/glibc-2.18/lib` is `/path/to/glibc-2.18/etc/ld.so.conf`, then `-rpath` should not be necessary. You didn't say *how* the application fails when you don't have `-rpath`. You also didn't say how `glibc-2.18` was configured. Both may be important for answering your question.

Comment: So: _First_ I followed your previous answer, but the program crashed because it could not find `libstdc++` (my original question). _Second_, with `strace` I figured `ld-2.18.so` didn't find `libstdc++` because it was only looking in subdirs of `/path/to/glibc-2.18/lib`. _Third_, I created `/path/to/glibc-2.18/etc/ld.so.conf`, put `/path/to/glibc-2.18/lib` at the top, followed by the std paths (`/lib`, `/usr/lib`, etc), and ran `/path/to/glibc-2.18/sbin/ldconfig` (with `-v`, confirming that `libc.so.6 -> 2.18` is seen _before_ `-> 2.15`). Now, if I use `--rpath` it works. [cont]

Comment: If I don't use `--rpath` (my question 2), I get a SEGV. `strace` shows `/path/to/glibc-2.18/etc/ld.so.cache` being the first successful `open()` call, so the libpath of `ld-2.18.so` is being used. But it also shows `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` being opened, which is `libc-2.15.so`, hence the SEGV. So my question 2 becomes, why is `libc-2.15.so` used by `ld-2.18.so` even though during its own `ldconfig`, `libc-2.18.so` is seen before `libc-2.15.so`?

Comment: I asked this (with more details) as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577638/library-path-order-for-alternate-glibc-dynamic-linker-ld-so