# Library path order for alternate glibc dynamic linker (ld.so)

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ld, glibc, dynamic-linking

I need to use an alternate `glibc` version, newer than the one installed on my system (`2.18` vs `2.15`). Several related issues are covered
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534436/how-to-use-alternate-glibc-with-existing-libstdc). The specific question I'm asking here is the following:

I set up the library path of the new dynamic linker (`ld-2.18.so`) so that the new `libc` (`libc-2.18.so`) is found ahead of the old `libc` (`libc-2.15.so`). However, when I try to run a program with the new `ld`, the old version of `libc` is picked up, generating a `SEGV`. *Why is that happening?*

Note: I know this can be fixed by using `--rpath` at compile time or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at run time. However, I would still like to understand why one of these is still needed.

The details follow:

I downloaded `glibc-2.18` and built it at `/opt/glibc-2.18`. By default, the file `/opt/glibc-2.18/etc/ld.so.conf` is missing. I created it, and updated the library cache of the new `glibc` as follows. I emphasize that: *the new `libc` is found before the old `libc`*:

```
$ cat /opt/glibc-2.18/etc/ld.so.conf
/opt/glibc-2.18/lib
/usr/local/lib
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa
/lib
/usr/lib
$ /opt/glibc-2.18/sbin/ldconfig -v |& grep -E '^[^'$'\t'']|libc\.'
/opt/glibc-2.18/sbin/ldconfig: Path `/opt/glibc-2.18/lib' given more than once
/opt/glibc-2.18/sbin/ldconfig: Can't stat /opt/glibc-2.18/lib64: No such file or directory
/opt/glibc-2.18/sbin/ldconfig: Can't stat /opt/glibc-2.18/libx32: No such file or directory
/opt/glibc-2.18/lib:
        libc.so.6 -> libc-2.18.so
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
        libc.so.6 -> libc-2.15.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa:
/lib:
/usr/lib:
```

Then, I created a simple C program:

```
$ cat <<EOF >a.c
> #include <stdio.h>
> int main()
> {
>     fprintf(stdout, "ok\n");
>     return 0;
> }
> EOF
$ g++ a.c
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x43b8484e3910072375d68418cb6327478266c0e9, not stripped
$ ldd a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd7ffe000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa7c47bd000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa7c4b9b000)
$ readelf -a a.out | grep lib
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
000000601000  000100000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __libc_start_main + 0
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
    46: 00000000004005f0     2 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __libc_csu_fini
    52: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_
    57: 0000000000400560   137 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __libc_csu_init
  000000: Version: 1  File: libc.so.6  Cnt: 1
$ objdump -x a.out | grep -A3 Version
Version References:
  required from libc.so.6:
    0x09691a75 0x00 02 GLIBC_2.2.5
```

As seen above, this program has the old `ld` hard-coded inside. I can forcefully run it with the new `ld`, and I expect the path of the new `ld` to be used (you can see the new `ld.so.cache` being opened). However, for some reason I'm trying to understand, *the old `libc` is found before the new `libc`*, generating a SEGV:

```
$ /opt/glibc-2.18/lib/ld-2.18.so ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ strace /opt/glibc-2.18/lib/ld-2.18.so ./a.out |& grep open
open("./a.out", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)     = 3
open("/opt/glibc-2.18/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

I can also compile with the new library and bake-in the new `ld` as follows:

```
$ g++ -L/opt/glibc-2.18/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/glibc-2.18/lib/ld-2.18.so a.c -o a.2.18.out
$ file a.2.18.out
a.2.18.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x25ab43f3d29b49fa21385a15e43325e9fb904e81, not stripped
$ ldd a.2.18.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa68da000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9df5cbe000)
    /opt/glibc-2.18/lib/ld-2.18.so => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9df609c000)
$ readelf -a a.2.18.out | grep lib
      [Requesting program interpreter: /opt/glibc-2.18/lib/ld-2.18.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
000000601000  000100000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __libc_start_main + 0
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
    54: 0000000000400600     2 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __libc_csu_fini
    60: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_
    65: 0000000000400570   137 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __libc_csu_init
  000000: Version: 1  File: libc.so.6  Cnt: 1
$ objdump -x a.2.18.out | grep -A3 Version
Version References:
  required from libc.so.6:
    0x09691a75 0x00 02 GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Still, if I try to run the new program the same thing happens, the old `libc` is being used instead of the new `libc`:

```
$ ./a.2.18.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ strace ./a.2.18.out |& grep open
open("/opt/glibc-2.18/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

With either executable, specifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.18/lib` makes it work. However, my question here is why that is still needed, given that the path of the new `ld` is configured at the beginning to pick up the new `libc` ahead of the old `libc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it, the issue was with the OS ABI version. That's the number indicated by `file`, such as:

```
$ file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so | grep -o "for GNU/Linux [0-9.]*"
for GNU/Linux 2.6.24
```

When `glibc` is configured with nothing other than `--prefix`, it builds by default with an ABI version *smaller(!!)* (in my case, `2.6.16`) than the default on the system (`2.6.24`). So `libc-2.18` has ABI version smaller than `libc-2.15`.

When `ldconfig` finds 2 versions of `libc.so.6` with different ABI numbers, it places them in `ld.so.cache` *in order of descending ABI number, not in order of appearance*. This can be checked by swapping their locations, rebuilding the cache (with `ldconfig`), and listing cache contents (with `ldconfig -p`). Only when 2 `libc.so.6` files have the same ABI version, do they get placed in the cache in order of appearance.

Configuring `glibc` with `--enable-kernel=2.6.24` causes it to use the same ABI version as the system, which in turn fixes the resolution issues in the question statement, without the need for an explicit `--rpath` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.