# Commands outputs ELF: zR: Error

Tags: terminal, linux-kernel, centos, elf

I was working on setting up a machine with centos 7 and somewhere along the line it seems I messed up and now most commands output some ELF error:

`[***** ~]$ python
python: �����: ELF: zR: Error 1227246965`

`[***** ~]$ ls
ls: : ELF: zR: Error 18446744071987891573`

Strangely some functions work putting `sudo` in front.

```
[***** ~]$ yum install gcc
/usr/bin/python: : ELF: zR: Error 18446744071568268661

[***** ~]$ sudo yum install gcc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
....
```

Any idea how I can go about troubleshooting this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google search points to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019728/linux-c-portable-binary-issue) similar problem.

What you probably did is install a copy of `libc.so.6` that is *incompatible* with your system loader (`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`) somewhere on your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

The reason commands work under `sudo` is likely that they ignore `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

You can unset `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and check whether the problem goes away.

Installing a copy of `libc.so.6` incorrectly is a very easy way to render your system un-bootable.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) if you need to have multiple GLIBC instances.

Comment: thank you, your analysis was correct! I installed brew and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` had these paths: /***/.linuxbrew/lib64:/***/.linuxbrew/lib. Unsetting this helped the problem go away. Thanks again!